# How to rename the file in S3 bucket through Lambda Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there any way to rename the file in S3 bucket through Lambda function? is there any link or code available to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Rename or Copy Files on AWS Lambda function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553447/how-to-rename-or-copy-files-on-aws-lambda-function)

Answer (score 1):

It is *not* possible to **rename** objects in Amazon S3 because the unique object identifier is the **Key**, which is also the name of the object.

Instead, you will need to **copy** the object to a new object, then delete the old object.

For example, if you were using Python, you would use:

- [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object)
- [`delete_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.delete_object)