# How do i create folders for each file when it comes in my s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3

is it possible to create a folder for each file coming in to my s3 bucket , something like this simple batch script i found where if you put this .bat file in a folder and run it, it creates a folder for each file. So basically every time a users file syncs to my s3 bucket it automatically creates a folder for each file.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*) do (
 if not "%%~ni" == "organize" (
  md "%%~ni" && move "%%~i" "%%~ni"
 )
)
```

Comment: Could you please clarify the end-result of what you would like to accomplish? Please edit your question to provide some examples of incoming files and what you would like to happen to them.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to understand is that [S3 does not have folders](https://serverfault.com/questions/435827/what-is-the-difference-between-buckets-and-folders-in-amazon-s3). Everything in a bucket in S3 is a file, or UI sugar meant to replicate the visual experience of a file system. A "folder" is nothing more than a prefix ending in `/` (with the caveat that, when you create an *empty* folder, S3 creates an invisible file to have **something** to refer to at that prefix).

Therefore, what you're trying to accomplish is effectively just *renaming* files, to give each file a unique prefix. You can do this in a number of ways:

If you want it to happen as files are written, I would recommend using [a lambda trigger](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) which triggers when an object is written, copies it to a new object with the prefix you desire, and deletes the original. You'll need to make sure, of course, to not trigger on the files the lambda itself writes - this can be accomplished by writing to a specific prefix (before your file-specific prefix) which you exclude from the lambda trigger.

If you want it to happen as a batch process (like the `bat` file you mention), you have many more options. You can write a lambda function that does the renaming, and hook it up to a Cloudwatch trigger to run on a schedule. You can also just write a bash script, using [the AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Comment: Yo that was a beautiful reply thanks , ill try with the lambda triggers but the problem is that im not a coder , are there any sample lambda triggers out there that can accomplish this.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I don't know of any. The pieces are certainly out there: [define a lambda that triggers on a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html), [except for a prefix](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-s3-adds-prefix-and-suffix-filters-for-lambda-function-triggering/). Put code in the lambda to [copy the file it's triggered on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553447/how-to-rename-or-copy-files-on-aws-lambda-function) to that excluded prefix, with a unique prefix added. Delete the original file.